# Counter-intuitive distribution of Child-Care Assistance in New Mexico, USA: Would my family be better off earning less?

Tags: united-states, benefits, child-care, new-mexico

My understanding of how NM's child-care assistance program works is that my family would be financially better off if our income were lower. I'm hoping someone can explain why I'm wrong.

**Eligibility for the CCA program:**
“The Child Care Assistance Program subsidizes the cost of child care for families at or below 400% of the federal poverty level that are working, in school, or searching for employment.”
[NM Child Care Assistance Program](https://nmececd.org/child-care-assistance)

**The CCA benefit:**
There is currently no co-pay, i.e. my understanding is that if you earn 399% of the FPL, then you get the full subsidy, which is $1925 pcm for an infant at 5 Star Child Care Center ([NM Child Care Provider Rates](https://api.realfile.rtsclients.com/PublicFiles/d4a60d4c4e7149c9830debdc01dbe554/8af1ae5e-95d9-40ff-a37d-c8319fc271b4/Child%20Care%20Rates%20082023.pdf)). My child attends such a center.

**The Federal Poverty Level:**
400% of the FPL for 2023 is $99,440 for a 3 person household like mine  ([HHS Poverty Guidelines for 2023](https://aspe.hhs.gov/topics/poverty-economic-mobility/poverty-guidelines)).

**Counter-intuititive financial consequences:**
So, if our gross household income were $100k, it seems we would pay ~9k in income tax and $23K in childcare, leaving ~$69k. If our income were $99k, we would pay ~$9k in taxes, leaving $91k.

Am I missing something crucial here? Is it really the case that we’d be $22k better off if we earned $99k instead of $100k?

**Efforts to find answers elsewhere:**
I called the NMECECD but the person I spoke to wasn't able to answer the question, only to confirm the eligibility threshold. I was told that if I apply for CCA then my question could be addressed in an eligibility interview, but it was unclear whether I would get an interview given that our family income is above the eligibility threshold of 400% FPL. I emailed the NMECECD but have not yet received a response.

Comment: Check with the state, if it's a state program. Most such taper off rather than cut off suddenly, since the last thing the want to do is discourage people from working.

Comment: Thanks, I called the state (NMECECD) and got no clarification, just a reiteration of the thresholds for eligibility. The person I spoke to confirmed the thresholds seem to have the information to address my questions. I emailed my a state address last week and haven't heard back yet. Maybe they're just overloaded and I'll hear back soon.

Comment: Re the tapering off: there used to be a copay, which was calculated based on your income, though even when this was the case, the copay hit a ceiling of ~$11k at 300% of the FPL, meaning that using the numbers in my question there would be a $22k-$11k=$11k disadvantage in earning $100k vs $99k.

Comment: [Copays were waived on May 1st 2022](https://www.nmececd.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/ECECD_CCA_Copayment_April2022_FINAL.pdf) and it seems like this policy is here to stay for a while as [recently update regulations](https://www.nmececd.org/2023/07/20/ececd-finalizes-child-care-regulations-to-make-child-care-affordable-for-most-new-mexico-families) require a three-month notice if the department decides to reinstate CCA copays.